# Why am I getting blank page when deploying Angular Spring war file to Apache Tomcat

Tags: angular, spring, maven, war

I am trying to package an Angular app together with a Spring Boot app as a war file so that I can deploy it to my Apache Tomcat server. I have built the angular app and copied the files to my /public/ folder so that Spring Boot can serve them. This is working and I am able to successfully access my web application.

After packaging the application as war file using Intellij I deploy the application but when I visit the page I get:

- A blank white page
- Dev Tools indicates `GET http://localhost:8080/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`
- Similar message for all other files inside of public folder other than index.html

[image: My target public directory]

This image shows my public directory after completing build and packaging war. I have tried a few different configurations but I am very new to maven I am just learning. Below is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>taskappmain</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>taskappmain</name>
  <description>taskAppMain</description>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>

                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/public</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>


       <workingDirectory>C:\Users\zemcd\IdeaProjects\AppWarPackage\taskAppFrontEnd</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>prod</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
            </configuration>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

and Also the package.json for my angular app:

```
{
  "name": "task-app-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "postbuild": "npm run deploy",
    "test": "ng test",
    "outDir": "../taskappmain\\src\\main\\resources\\public",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
}, 
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
"typescript": "~2.7.2",
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.3.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I would like to know:

- what I am doing wrong when I am packaging war file?
- How can I make my resources accessible for the angular app when packaged as war file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by changing the href in my base tag. Because I was deploying the application on Tomcat and it was not being deployed at the path '/' my application was unable to find it's required resources.

Comment: what is the href in your base tag that you changed? What did you change it to? Also: what did the function you used to return the index page in your Spring Boot server look like?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the next build options:

```
ng build --prod --aot --base-href="."
```

Also, importing in app.module.tx

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy  } from '@angular/common'; 
providers: [
{provide : LocationStrategy , useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

],

So, the url will be like this, with the hash symbol:

```
http://192.168.220.xyz:8080/yourapp/#/youcomponent
```

As a comment, the main issue was in reloading using:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **index.html** file you have to do the following change,
set `<base href="/">` to `<base href=".">`